# Tower of fields

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field and $\mathbb{K}$ be its extension and $\alpha$ $\in$ $\mathbb{K}$. Now, we know that $\mathbb{F}$ $\subset$ $\mathbb{F(\alpha)}$. But why $\mathbb{F(\alpha)}$ $\subset$ $\mathbb{K}$?

Comment: What definition of $\mathbb{F}(\alpha)$ are you using?

Comment: I am looking at them as vectors in the basis $\lbrace 1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\ldots,\alpha^{n-1}$ over $\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: By Definition, $F(\alpha)$ is the smallest *field* containing $F$ and the member $\alpha$ and also contained in  $K$. Now we know $K$ is field and that smallest field is surely smaller than $K$ :)

Comment: Thank you. I did not know this definition. I am new to abstract algebra.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $\mathbb{F}(\alpha)$ is the smalles possible field which has $\mathbb{F}$ as a subfield, and which contains $\alpha$. Since $\mathbb{K}$ satisfies both of these conditions, we must have that $\mathbb{F}(\alpha) \subset \mathbb{K}$.

One way to think of it is that $\mathbb{F}(\alpha)$ is the field generated by elements of $\mathbb{F}$ and taking expressions that involve $\alpha$ as well. But note that since $\mathbb{F} \subset \mathbb{K}$ and that $\alpha \in \mathbb{K}$, it follows that any such expression is also an element of $\mathbb{K}$.

Answer (score 0):

All the elements of $\mathbb{F(\alpha)}$ have the form $R(\alpha)$ with $R$ a rational function with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}.$